# How can I create a value type that can be implemented similar to a Native type

Tags: c#, struct

I would like to create a Type 'Q'.

What I would like to be able to do with the type Q is assign a value similar to the way we assign to native types.

So if the definition were:

```
public struct Q
{

}
```

I would like the implementation to be:

```
Q val = 1.0f
```

When we look at the struct for a System.Single, we can see that it does not declare any values. But I cannot make sense of what they are doing to enable them to assign a value to the struct itself.  How can I make it so that I can assign a value directly to the struct as they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"When we look at the struct for a System.Single, we can see that it does not declare any values." That's not correct. Here's the declaration:

```cs
 public readonly struct Single : IComparable, IConvertible, ISpanFormattable, IComparable<float>, IEquatable<float>
    {
        private readonly float m_value; // Do not rename (binary serialization)
        // ...
    }
```

The field `m_value` is the member field that takes the value when an instance of `Single` is created. Since it's the only field it's identical to the whole object instance for a value type.

What is different for the built-in-types is that they allow automatic implicit assignment from a value. If you want that for your own types, you need to explicitly declare such an assignment operator. These can be **implicit** or **explicit**. You can find examples on how to do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators). Here's a modified example for your case:

```cs
public readonly struct MyQ
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public MyQ(int v)
    {
        _value = v;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyQ(int b) => new MyQ(b);

    public override string ToString() => $"{_value}";
}
```

This can be used as:

```cs
   MyQ a = default;
   a = 2;
```

Comment: I don't see the private readonly in the metadata that vscode shows me. I guess that was the missing piece to the puzzle.
Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was needing to understand.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Single.cs) is the source of the latest version.